# Android Studio Overriding onCreateView

Tags: android, android-studio, shortcut

In Android Studio, `ctrl+o` can be used to override the function `onCreateView` in the current class. However, when I search in the class `Fragment` for `onCreateView`, why can I not find it?

[My editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ci40.png) and [the override dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMFkm.png)

Comment: Because in fragment you are trying to override you already created function onCreateView

Comment: the results for `ctrl+o` does not include the methods if they are already overridden in current class. So make sure you not overridden that method previously. Also you can search for methods by typing the method name after pressing `ctrl+o` try that too because it may at somewhere else in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's already overridden in your class.  Android Studio has no reason to show you a method to override when it's already in your class.  It will show you the ones that are not yet overridden, so that when you select it, it will create the method for you in the current class.